Generating current limited bipolar pulses with MCU and H-bridge?
I'm trying to design a neuro-stimulator-like circuit around an
ESP32-S3. The output needs to be bipolar / biphasic (it's floating so an
H-bridge will do), current limited, and the current needs to be controllable
from the ESP32, likely with a digipot or DAC.
The ESP32 is likely too slow to be in the control loop, but is fast enough to generate the 4 signals for the H-bridge.
Let me preface this by saying that the parameters I want to achieve are:

a train of 3 biphasic pulses (plus-minus x 3, with 1 ms of pause in between) at
most once a second - means the average power is extremely low
pulse length 50-150 µs per phase (if it's 50 µs, we can say the frequency is
20 kHz)
current limited to 1-10 mA, adjustable by the microcontroller,
with max voltage of 120 V into a load of 10-100 kΩ

I have several ideas on how to achieve this, but they all seem to be a bit overkill, so I'm turning to you for solutions on how to simplify this circuit.
It's for an open-source project that needs to be as cheap and as small as possible (fewer components = better).
I also have a working prototype
that creates the required waveform with a bootstrapped improved Howland current
pump, which is extremely overkill - it has a lot of components and requires a
bipolar power supply (so 2 flyback transformers or a 2-secondary one).
Moreover, I don't neet to generate arbitrary current waveforms,
I just need short bursts of current-limited pulses.
Also, it uses many components, some of which are relatively expensive.
I also don't benefit from having ± rails, because the output is floating anyway
(a double-insulated, battery powered device).
So for the new design, what comes to mind is having a single HV power supply,
an H-bridge for making bipolar (biphasic) pulses from that voltage, and some
sort of a current-limiting circuit with an adjustable current.
For the PSU, what I currently have is a little SMD flyback transformer
(Coilcraft LPR6235-253PMRC) run with a MOSFET, and the PWM @ 100 kHz is generated by the ESP32-S3. This generates some
120 V from the battery's 3.2 - 4.2 V and charges an electrolytic cap. I don't
think this part can be improved much, save for a better snubber circuit.
I have a 3.3 V rail, an unregulated 3.2-4.2 battery voltage, and a 120 V from the
flyback. If it's possible, I'd rather not add another SMPS converter for an
intermediary rail.
For the actual current switching and limiting part, I want to use something
like this:
https://oshwlab.com/pscdietrich/high-voltage-h-bridge
I'd likely use some NPNs that can handle the 120 V, same goes for the MOSFETs.
ESP32-S3's GPIO module allows changing the states of many pins in 1 clock
cycle, so I can use it to generate the signals to drive the H-bridge (I'll add
dead time between switches just in case).
An alternative would be using a chip like DRV8833 to drive the MOSFET H-bridge.
As for the current limiting part, this comes to mind:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ab/sboa174d/sboa174d.pdf?ts=1723924270977
I could use something like an INA240 with a small current sensing resistor on the
low side, and its output could either drive a schmitt-trigger-input quad
AND-gate that ANDs the h-bridge driving signals with the output of the
H-Bridge signal. The reference voltage would be provided by a DAC5571.
Another solution would be to take the output of the INA240 and feed it into a
MOSFET or BJT that supplies the power for the top side of the H-bridge.
This would likely work even if the MOSFET ends up in the ohmic region most of the
time while actually switching on, or I use a BJT, because I only need 3 x 150 µs
pulses (up-down) every 5 seconds at most, which means the average current and
power is miniscule and the device is unlikely to overheat.
The third solution would be using this circuit, or a low-side equivalent,
with a digipot for R2. I don't think that'd work right off the bat, the voltage
across the digipot might not be too high, but it's likely that it's offset too
high compared to the MCU voltage.

A while ago I have built a little battery supplied electro acupuncture device.
This is a simplified extract of the schematic, that shows the HV output stage. I did not include the HV measurement, safety check and regulation loop.
The center tap of the HV split supply is connected to the output electrode, the body reference is GND of the circuit.
R01 is the current measurement shunt, and defines the analog input range of 1 V / mA. This is not perfectly exact, because the base current also flows through R1, but it was good enough for my application.
R04 is added to allow a stable OpAmp output with a tiny voltage dead band if none of the two transistors is driven and allows an OpAmp offset error.
The HV generator PWM must start with a delay, because C14 must be charged to the voltage difference between DAC neutral and GND to avoid a turn on HV peak.
I just wanted to show, that not always a full H-bridge is required for bipolar outputs like this.
Do not use this solution without an extra isolation if the power supply is related to the grid.

